# Windows Task Scheduler: Why is the minimum frequency once per minute?

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

The Windows Task Scheduler will not allow you to run a task more frequently than once per minute. To get around this we can set up multiple triggers to run the task every minute but with staggered start times. While this works, it does feel like a workaround which probably isn't the intended way to run tasks more frequently.

Why is this limitation in place? Is there a better way to run tasks more frequently than once per minute than using the staggered start method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason that `cron` doesn't allow you to run tasks at schedules shorter than one minute: If you have a job that needs running more than once a minute, a scheduled task is the wrong tool for the job.

Technically I'm guessing that the task scheduler only wakes up to check for tasks once a minute, and that probably dates back to when CPU cycles were more precious.

The correct way to solve this problem is to have your program register itself as a daemon and trigger itself through an internal timer at whatever interval it needs.

Comment: Thanks Mark. For other Windows users who weren't aware, a daemon is the same as a Windows service.